# Read Ethernet/IP Device with Known Object Class, Assembly Instance, Attribute ID using CPPPO

Tags: python, iot, industrial, cognex

Having a little trouble getting basic information out of an Industrial Ethernet/IP Cognex Barcode Scanner.

Per the Cognex Documentation *"The DataMan ID Reader Object (Class Code: 0x79)"*  Input Assembly Instance = 11  It then shows a table for this object and at Byte 14~15 = Result Data Length with is a 16-bit Integer.

```
From cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple, proxy 
vendor, product_name, zz = proxy_simple( '10.202.180.90' ).read( [('@1/1/1','INT'),('@1/1/7','SSTRING'),('@0x79/11/14','UINT')] )
print(product_name)
print(vendor)
print(zz)

>>>['DataMan DM262 Reader']
>>>[678]
>>>None
```

I get the product name, vendor number, but can not get it to return anything for the Result Data Length.  Another table in the documentation states Attribute ID 0X17 AND type UNIT for this same data.  So I tried ('@0x79/11/0x17','UNIT') but that returned 'None' also.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas.

[Picture of AttributeID Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMF5N.png)
[Picture of Input Assembly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm7HD.png)
https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo

Answer (score 1):

Try using the telnetlib library in python.

```
from telnetlib import Telnet
import time

tn = Telnet('192.168.1.112', 23, 2)
trigger = "||>TRIGGER ON".encode('ascii') + b'\r\n'
tn.write(trigger)
time.sleep(0.1)
resultstring = tn.read_very_eager().decode('utf-8')
tn.close()
```

I had to add a short delay to give the scanner time to have the results ready. From there you can process the result string as needed. For example, I used:

```
if resultstring == '000':
    pass
else:
    resultstring = resultstring[:-2]
print(resultstring)
```

due to '000' being the bad read string and a good read adding the \r\n at the end of the string.

The DataMan Control Commmands chm file shows you all the commands you can use. https://support.cognex.com/en/documentation/dataman/dm-260

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I should had clarified I am really just trying to get it to work on EIP as I have had it working over Modbus for some time but EIP seems to be the natural progression of the industry to a new standard and gives me access to more devices so I'm trying to get something I know such as this device to work over a different protocol.  That is why I am trying to use cpppo

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally figure it out.  The CIP Object is 0x79, the Instance is 1, and Attribute is 0x10.  This got me an integer array with all the data I need.

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple
vendor, product_name, zz = proxy_simple( '10.202.180.66' ).read( [('@1/1/1','INT'),('@1/1/7','SSTRING'),('@0x79/1/0x10','SINT')] )

print(vendor)
print(product_name)
print(zz)
```

[678]
['DataMan DM374']
[20, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 48, 54, 52, 48, 53, 50, 50, 55, 49, 48, 56, 50, 57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[Output Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUFzi.png)